# Вывод номера строки

Tags: c++

Интересует написание функции, которая сможет выводить номер строки, на которой она вызывается. Это должно выглядеть как-то так:

> [image: Пример]

Это вообще возможно?

Comment: `__LINE__` макро можно завернуть в подобие функции. Но вообще-то это отдает printf-отладкой.

Comment: @VTT вопрос, а этот макрос универсален? Все ли компиляторы его поддерживают?

Comment: @andy.37 Да, это стандартный макрос.

Comment: Если бы это был GCC, тогда можно было бы сделать `void string_number(int line = __builtin_LINE()) {std::cout << line << '\n';}`.

Comment: @VTT [Но вообще-то это отдает printf-отладкой] Иногда (и довольно часто) для встроенных систем printf-отладка это единственный выход.

Comment: Ну если только подадобится

Comment: @pepsicoca1 это да...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define string_number() { cout << "File: " << __FILE__ << ", line " << __LINE__ << endl; }
```

Стандартно и переносимо :)